# How use centerCrop in SplashActivity

Tags: android, bitmap, styles, android-manifest

In my `SlashActivity` I use only `AndroidManifest` and `style` as advised here https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/.

And in `SplashActivity` I want use `splash.jpg`, but this picture changing to screen size.

How I can use `centerCrop` in my `style` file or are there other solutions?

My drawble:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:drawable="@color/colorMaterialWhite"/>

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

AndroidManifest:

```
        <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

SplashActivity:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavigationActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
 }
}
```

Style:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

Comment: If you see the example, he used layerlist for drawable, one layer for background and other layer for logo center cropped

Comment: @MohammedAtif I use this too, I updated my code

Comment: then in your second item tag, add layout height and width to wrap content and gravity as center

Comment: I think you will have to use a layout with ImageView to center-crop

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have also followed this blog while creating my Splash screen. Generally, the splash screen has a background color and the logo of your app and you can set it as a background. So, you should not require to centerCrop the image in Splash screen. In case that need is there, I would strongly recommend to edit the image using any editor instead of programmatically doing it.

Comment: Yes. The mipmap is the main icon of your app. Generally that is used.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add padding to your splash image.

Inside the item tag add `android:top`, `android:bottom`, `android:right`, `android:left`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:drawable="@color/colorMaterialWhite"/>

<item
   android:top="200dp"
   android:bottom="200dp"
   android:left="200dp"
  android:right="200dp">
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: I think this is bad solution.